# Please get rid of this ghost Suggested Edit

Tags: support, stack-overflow, suggested-edits

We have a post in the SO Suggested Edit queue that can't be voted on because it was migrated.

Can we get that removed from the queue please?

[image: Suggested Edit Ghost]

Comment: I thought it sat there as an example of a suggested edit ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dismissed.

You can probably just flag for moderator attention on the question next time...